# Using a special French character in a view with razor application

Tags: .net, css, asp.net-mvc, html

I have an asp .net mvc4 application in which I have a problem in the encoding in this view:

```
@model Planning.Models.Affaire
@{

    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/Template.cshtml";
}

@section logout {
    <a href='@Url.Action("Index", "Calendar")'><img src="~/Content/images/restart-1.png"/></a>
    <a href='@Url.Action("Logout", "Home")' style="margin-left: 91.3%"><img src="~/Content/images/images.jpg" style="width:37px; height:37px" /></a>
    }
<head>
    <style>
    input {
    border: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
    background: #fff;
    color: #333;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    margin: 5px 0 6px 0;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 300px;
    }
        a {
            font-size:14px;
        }

        </style>
</head>
<br />
<br />
<h2 style="color:red ; margin-left: 40%">Ajouter une séquence</h2>
<br />
<br />

<form action="/Calendar/SaveSequence" method="post" style="margin-left: 33%; ">
           <div >
            <strong style="color:blue ">La description  de la séquence</strong>
            <input type="text" name="description" value="" style="margin-left:15.5%; width:50%" /> 
           </div>
            <br />

        <input type="text" name="id" value="@Model.Id_affaire" style="margin-left:15.5%; width:50%; visibility:hidden" />          <br />

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Enregistrer" />
        </p>

</form>
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Retour à la liste", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

I get this result :

[image: result]

The problem is in the letter `é`: it's appears in `<strong style="color:blue ">La description de la séquence</strong>` and disappeared in `<h2 style="color:red ; margin-left: 40%">Ajouter une séquence</h2>` .

Why this happens? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution, which is not very good but works is using the code `&eacute;`

```
<strong style="color: blue">La description de la s&eacute;quence</strong>
<h2 style="color: red; margin-left: 40%;">Ajouter une s&eacute;quence</h2>.
```

A smarter solution would be to declare UTF-8 encoding in the head tag like so:

```
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
```